# Integrate a Load Balancer IP given by OVH with a Nginx Ingress Controller on a k8s cluster

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, lxc, ovh

I have a Load Balancer IP provided by OVH that I want to use with Nginx Ingress Controller but on a on-premises cluster. There are several guide s to do that using OVH Managed Kubernetes but it is not possible for me since I already a cluster.

I tried to use the LoadBalancerIP option using Helm and without Helm as well...

Comment: Kubernetes LoadBalancer Services only work on services where the lb can be auto provisioned (AWS, GKE, Azure, Docker for X, Minikube)

Answer (score 2):

You should expose Nginx Ingress Controller as NodePort and point your OVH Load Balancer to your workers as endpoints.

User ---> OVH LB ----> Nginx Ingress on workers

Comment: It's probably worth noting that the NodePort is a separate entity to the Nginx Ingress itself. The NodePort forwards tcp connections onto the Nginx Ingress controllers.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for both you answer. I tried what you recommended but I think I'm missing a point. TO be more clear :

1/ The user part -> I have a OVH LB connected to a server of 3 node, this LB selects a node to be used by a user (round robin)

2/ Once a node had been selected, the user should be able to access to whatever service inside Kubernetes even if the service is not on this node by using the LoadBalancer IP.

For the 2nd point, I tried to expose/create an endpoint for the Nginx Ingress Controller where I gave the LB's IP, but I don't know if I have to create an Ingress object for each service (only 2-3 like grafana, prometheus..). I tried it but it didn't work. I also tried to create an Ingress for the service where I gave the LB IP but it didn't work. Note that my k8s cluster is on LXD containers which are inside 3 connected servers (one LXD container by server node). Also, concerning the OVH LoadBalancer, I'm not very confident with the purpose of Outbound IPs (which is a CIDR range)..

I understand that my OVH LB cannot be auto provisioned, but since its job is done outside of k8s (just attributing a node to a user), the problem is : how does the node can access the service based on a URL like grafana.example.com? I was using MetalLB as an internal LB and it worked fine but now i'm struggling with the OVH LB..